# Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'Ember.TextArea'

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use the Ember.TextArea class but keep running in to the following error...

```
Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'Ember.TextArea'
```

Here's my handlebars template...

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dashboard">
  <div>
    {{view Ember.TexArea valueBinding="content.description" rows="1"}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Here's my model...

```
App.Dashboard = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  thumbnailUrl: DS.attr('string'),
  charts: DS.hasMany('App.Chart')
});
```

Here's my view...

```
App.DashboardView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'dashboard',
  currentUserBinding: 'App.currentUser',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log('dashboard didInsertElement');

    $("#right-content").sortable({
      handle: '.js-sortable-handle'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: There is a typo in your template; you have `Ember.TexArea` instead of `Ember.TextArea`.

Comment: but the thrown error says Ember.TextArea, must be some copy/paste issue